# jQuery parameters replace and upload between two strings in all URL's

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, string, redirect

WordPress' FacetWP plugin has a 'facetwp-loaded' jQuery event that allows for changes when facets are refreshed.

This is the 'facetwp-loaded' event's usage from FacetWP's documentation:

```
(function($) {
    $(document).on('facetwp-loaded', function() {

        // Changes go here

    });
})(jQuery);
```

Facets produce URL's like:

```
http://website.com/hotels?fwp_location=worldwide
```

or

```
http://website.com/hotels/worldwide?fwp_location=europe
```

So I would like to make a global Regex redirection to substitute what is between

```
hotels
```

and

```
=
```

with

```
/
```

In the above examples, that would result in:

```
http://website.com/hotels/worldwide
```

or

```
http://website.com/hotels/europe
```

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**

I've tried different Regex methods, but it seems to need jQuery parameter replace/update.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a way to test this using the Wordpress regex engine, so you'll have to check it, but it works in the R regex engine. Hopefully Wordpress supports perl style regex expressions.

Regex: Match: `(?<=hotels).*?=` and replace with `/`

In this case the piece of the string we want to remove is preceded by "hotels" and ends with an equal sign. So we want to match everything immediately after hotels, ending at the equal sign. To start matching immediately after "hotels" but not include it, we need to look backwards. So we use a look behind before the match. `(?<=hotels)` means look backwards from the current position in the string, and see if "hotels" precedes the current position. So when the engine gets to the "/" after hotels, it looks back and sees hotels (but it doesn't match, because it's a look behind). `.` matches any character, `*` means match zero or more (so zero or more of any character), and `?` modifies the `*` telling the star to match zero or more characters, but only until the next character can be matched, in this case `=`.

Comment: I've read answers from other threads and tried some solutions like that, with look behind and forward. But I think the problem is that I don't know how to put the code. Could you give me a step-by-step, please? Thanks

Comment: @Karls I added a more detailed explanation, let me know if that helps

Comment: Don't get me wrong @mako212, but I know what every bit of that code means, I did some research before asking. The problem is that it doesn't seem to work -and others that are variations of it. When loading a new page after clicking a facet option, the new URL is in the usual `http://website.com/hotels?fwp_location=worldwide` format. If I press F5, then the URL changes to my desired format, but then FacetWP won't load its facet on that page. So I think this must be done with jQuery's parameter replace/upload, not any kind of Regex.

Comment: After searching a lot, the problem with @mako212 answer is that javascript doesn't have 'lookbehind', so his regex won't work. Also, it seems that after replacing the URL, it has to be redirected to the new URL. Otherwise, Facets get frozen.